# Using KbQueueCheck to continuously check for device input

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, timing, psychtoolbox

I am using PsychToolbox to run an experiment on a fMRI scanner. I want to collect the timepoints of pulses sent out by the scanner. If you are not familiar with this topic: A scanner gives out a signal - equivalent to pressing keyboard digit "5" - in defined time-intervals. The first such signal starts the code, such that measurements by the scanner, and starting time of the code are synchronized. My code is sequential, as sketched out below. How could I implement a loop which at any time checks for these inputed "5", even though my main code runs in a "for"-loop?

My code:

```
% here I wait for the scanner to input a "5", then my code will start
KbQueueCreate;
KbQueueStart;
Trigger = KbName('5%');

keyboard = -1;
AllowedKeys = zeros(256,1); %Disable all keys
AllowedKeys([LeftPress RightPress MiddlePress]) = 1; %Also allow escape always.


while 1

      [pressed, firstPress] = KbQueueCheck();

    if firstPress(Trigger)
        startExperiment = GetSecs;
break
    end
end


KbQueueStop;
KbQueueRelease;

% In the foolowing loop, the main experiment runs. here I show a screen, 
% signal etc.

for i = 1:nrTrials


% here I would like to have code checking for scanner inputs

end
```

The function KbQueueCheck should check for any keyboard input starting from the most recent call to KbQueueStart.
Any input is very welcome.

Comment: in how far? Can you please elaborate a bit more? I really want to solve this problem. thank you

Comment: So what have *you* tried to accomplish this? All I see is "I wrote the first half of my required code, please write the second part for me". And since SO is not a code-writing service I'd say this question in its current state is off-topic as such.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, and if you look at my other questions this is not how I use SO. But in this case I really don't have a clue where to start at - that is not really nice, but the way it is in that case. I know that for instance I could possible create while loops for particular parts of the code, but then again I would miss some trigger inputs. Btw, I also have not asked for my code to be written, but also a comment like "just use parfor" is as general and not so helpful..

Comment: See this: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/308386-create-keyboard-listener-to-interrupt-a-running-function

Comment: Many thanks yuval, but as I understand this example, they look for keypresses in a break during two parts of code - I think I could implement that, but what I want is actually ongoing detection of keypresses. tx

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for throwing general ideas around, that's more of a question for quora or [softwareengineering.SE]. Also having a good track record on SO in terms of other questions does not alleviate the rules for you if you find they're not to your liking for a particular question.

Comment: I've done stuff like this in the past, I had to add a short pause so that the program could actually check the input. pause(.0001) worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do the similar stuff with our scanner, so I providing a function I use. I normally only detect first trigger to start the stimulus, and won't read later triggers. But I do register all triggers, as well as other response, in the background, so I can check the events in case there is any problem.

The function, KbQueue.m, can do almost all related response collection, including background key register. Please read the help for how to use different functionality. Some part of the code, such as different keyboard indices, is not well tested for MAC and Linux.

```
function varargout = KbQueue(cmd, param)
% KbQueueXXX series functions have some good features: 
%  1. detect short key event, like those from fOPR KbCheck may miss; 
%  2. detect only interested keys; 
%  3. buffer key event while code is running. 
% 
% But the syntax of KbQueueXXX is a little inconvenient due to the flexibility.
% 
% This code tries to provide a convenient wrapper for practical purpose, by
% sacrificing some flexibility, like deviceIndex etc. By default, KbQueue
% detects events for the first device (this doesn't seem the case for Windows,
% where it detects all devices). If you have more than one keyboard, and like to
% detect a different one, you have to add following in your code: 
% 
% global KbQueueDevice; KbQueueDevice = 2; 
% 
% where 2 means the second device. You need to find this index for your target
% keyboard.
% 
% KbQueue('start', keys); 
% - Create a queue and start it. The second input specify the keys to be queued.
% The default are numbers 1~5, both keyboard and keypad numbers. The key names
% adopt those with KbName('UnifyKeyNames'). The 'start' command can be called
% more than once to update new keys. If it is not called, other subfunctions
% will call it with the default keys automatically. 
% 
% Example:
% KbQueue('start', {'LeftArrow' 'RightArrow'}); % start to queue 2 arrows
% 
% The input keys can also be 256-element keyCode, such as that returned by
% KbCheck etc. It can also be the index in the keyCode, such as that returned by
% KbQueue('wait') etc.
% 
% nEvents = KbQueue('nEvents' [, 'type']);
% - Return number of events in the queue. The default event type is 'press',
% which returns the number of keypress. It can be 'release' or 'all', which will
% return number of release events or all events.
% 
% [pressTime, pressCode] = KbQueue('wait' [, secs or keys]);
% - Wait for a new event, and return key press time and keycode. During the
% wait, pressing Escape will abort code execution, unless 'Escape' is included
% in defined keys.
% 
% If there is no second input, this will wait forever till a defined key by
% previous 'start' command is detected.
% 
% If the second input is numeric, it will be interpreted as the seconds to wait,
% and wait for a key defined by previous 'start' command is pressed, or the
% seconds has elapsed, whichever is earlier. If there is no any event during the
% time window, both output will be empty. For example:
% 
% [t, key] = KbQueue('wait', 1); % wait for 1 sec or a key is detected
% 
% If the second input is a string or cellstr, it will be interpreted as the
% key(s) to detect. The provided keys here affects only this call, i.e. it has
% no effect on the queue keys defined by previous 'start' command. For example:
% 
% t = KbQueue('wait', {'5%' '5'}); % wait till 5 is pressed
% 
% [pressCodeTime, releaseCodeTime] = KbQueue('check' [, t0]);
% - Return first and last press keycode and times for each queued key, and
% optionally release keycode and times. The output will be empty if there is no
% buffered response. Both output are two row vector, with the first row for the
% keycode and second row for times. If the second input t0, default 0, is
% provided, the returned times will be relative to t0. For example:
% 
% press = KbQueue('check'); % return 1st and last key press in the queue 
% pressedKey = KbName(press(1, :); % convert keycode into key names
% 
% KbQueue('flush');
% - Flush events in the current queue.
% 
% t = KbQueue('until', whenSecs);
% - This is the same as WaitSecs('UntilTime', whenSecs), but allows to exit by
% pressing ESC. If whenSecs is not provided or is already passed, this still
% checks ESC, so allows use to quit. For example:
% KbQueue('until', GetSecs+5); % wait for 5 secs from now
% KbQueue('until'); % only check ESC exit
% 
% [pressCodeTime, releaseCodeTime] = KbQueue('stop' [, t0]);
% - This is similar to 'check' command, but it returns all queued events since
% last 'flush', or since the queue was  started. It also stops and releases the
% queue. This provides a way to check response in the end of a session. For
% example: 
% KbQueue('start', {'5%' '5'}); % start to queue 5 at beginning of a session
% KbQueue('flush'); % optionally remove unwanted events at a time point 
% t0 = GetSecs; % the start time of your experiment 
% % run your experiment
% pressCodeTime = KbQueue('stop', t0); % get all keycode and time

% 10/2012   wrote it, xiangrui.li@gmail.com
% 12/2012   try to release queue from GetChar etc, add nEvents
% 11/2014   try to use response device for OSX and Linux

persistent kCode started evts;
global KbQueueDevice; % allow to change in user code
if isempty(started), started = false; end
if nargin<1 || isempty(cmd), cmd = 'start'; end
if any(cmd=='?'), subFuncHelp('KbQueue', cmd); return; end

if strcmpi(cmd, 'start')
    if started, BufferEvents; end
    if nargin<2
        param = {'1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '1!' '2@' '3#' '4$' '5%'};
    end
    KbName('UnifyKeyNames');
    if ischar(param) || iscellstr(param) % key names
        kCode = zeros(256, 1);
        kCode(KbName(param)) = 1;
    elseif length(param)==256 % full keycode
        kCode = param;
    else
        kCode = zeros(256, 1);
        kCode(param) = 1;        
    end
    if isempty(KbQueueDevice), KbQueueDevice = responseDevice; end
    try KbQueueReserve(2, 1, KbQueueDevice); end %#ok
    KbQueueCreate(KbQueueDevice, kCode);
    KbQueueStart(KbQueueDevice);
    started = true;
    return;
end

if ~started, KbQueue('start'); end

if strcmpi(cmd, 'nEvents')
    BufferEvents;
    n = length(evts);
    if n, nPress = sum([evts.Pressed] == 1);
    else nPress = 0;
    end
    if nargin<2, param = 'press'; end
    if strncmpi(param, 'press', 5)
        varargout{1} = nPress;
    elseif strncmpi(param, 'release', 7)
        varargout{1} = n - nPress;
    else
        varargout{1} = n;
    end
elseif strcmpi(cmd, 'check')
    [down, p1, r1, p2, r2] = KbQueueCheck(KbQueueDevice);
    if ~down 
        varargout = repmat({[]}, 1, nargout);
        return;
    end
    if nargin<2, param = 0; end
    i1 = find(p1); i2 = find(p2);
    varargout{1} = [i1 i2; [p1(i1) p2(i2)]-param];
    if nargout>1
        i1 = find(r1); i2 = find(r2);
        varargout{2} = [i1 i2; [r1(i1) r2(i2)]-param];
    end
elseif strcmpi(cmd, 'wait')
    endSecs = GetSecs;
    secs = inf; % wait forever unless secs provided
    newCode = kCode; % use old keys unless new keys provided
    if nargin>1 % new keys or secs provided
        if isempty(param), param = inf; end
        if isnumeric(param) % input is secs
            secs = param;
        else % input is keys
            newCode = zeros(256, 1);
            newCode(KbName(param)) = 1;
        end
    end
    esc = KbName('Escape');
    escExit = ~newCode(esc);
    newCode(esc) = 1;
    changed = any(newCode~=kCode);
    if changed % change it so we detect new keys
        BufferEvents;
        KbQueueCreate(KbQueueDevice, newCode);
        KbQueueStart(KbQueueDevice); % Create and Start are twins here :)
    else
        KbQueueFlush(KbQueueDevice, 1); % flush KbQueueCheck buffer
    end
    endSecs = endSecs+secs;
    while 1
        [down, p1] = KbQueueCheck(KbQueueDevice);
        if down || GetSecs>endSecs, break; end
        WaitSecs('YieldSecs', 0.005);
    end
    if changed % restore original keys if it is changed
        BufferEvents;
        KbQueueCreate(KbQueueDevice, kCode);
        KbQueueStart(KbQueueDevice);
    end
    if isempty(p1)
        varargout = repmat({[]}, 1, nargout);
        return;
    end
    ind = find(p1);
    if escExit && any(ind==esc)
        error('User pressed ESC. Exiting ...'); 
    end
    varargout = {p1(ind) ind};
elseif strcmpi(cmd, 'flush')
    KbQueueFlush(KbQueueDevice, 3); % flush both buffers
    evts = [];
elseif strcmpi(cmd, 'until')
    if nargin<2 || isempty(param), param = 0; end
    while 1
        [down, t, kc] = KbCheck(-1);
        if down && kc(KbName('Escape'))
            error('User pressed ESC. Exiting ...'); 
        end
        if t>=param, break; end
        WaitSecs('YieldSecs', 0.005);
    end
    if nargout, varargout = {t}; end
elseif strcmpi(cmd, 'stop')
    KbQueueStop(KbQueueDevice);
    started = false;
    if nargout
        BufferEvents;
        if isempty(evts)
            varargout = repmat({[]}, 1, nargout);
            return;
        end

        isPress = [evts.Pressed] == 1;
        if nargin<2, param = 0; end
        varargout{1} = [[evts(isPress).Keycode] 
                        [evts(isPress).Time]-param];
        if nargout>1
            varargout{2} = [[evts(~isPress).Keycode] 
                            [evts(~isPress).Time]-param];
        end
    end
    KbQueueRelease(KbQueueDevice);
else 
    error('Unknown command: %s.', cmd);
end

    function BufferEvents % buffer events so we don't lose them
        n = KbEventAvail(KbQueueDevice);
        if n<1, return; end
        for ic = 1:n
            foo(ic) = KbEventGet(KbQueueDevice); %#ok
        end
        if isempty(evts), evts = foo;
        else evts = [evts foo];
        end
    end

end

function idx = responseDevice
    if IsWin, idx = []; return; end % all keyboards

    clear PsychHID; % refresh
    [ind, pName] = GetKeyboardIndices;
    if IsOSX
        idx = ind(1); % based on limited computers
    else % Linux
        for i = length(ind):-1:1
            if ~isempty(strfind(pName{i}, 'HIDKeys')) || ...
                ~isempty(strfind(pName{i}, 'fORP')) % faked, need to update
                idx = ind(i);
                return;
            end
            idx = ind(end); % based on limited computers
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Either don't answer, or don't put a message on top of your answer that this question doesn't fit SO.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're going about this all wrong. There are much simpler ways to capture and process events without involving expensive for loops at all. Specifically, matlab (and octave) do this most effectively via graphics handle instances (even though you don't necessarily need a graphics object to be visible for it).

Here's a very simple example (I created this on octave, but it should also work on matlab). Run it to see how it works, then study and modify accordingly.

```matlab
%% In file 'run_fMRI_experiment.m'
 % Main experiment function
 function fMRIData = run_fMRI_experiment
   global fMRIData;
   F = figure;
   text(-1,0,{'Glorious Experiment, she is now runnink, yes?', 'Please to be pressink "5", I will collectink data.', '', 'Please to be pressink key of escapeness when finishedski, da?'}, 'fontsize', 14); 
   axis off; axis ([-1, 1, -1, 1]); 
   set (F, 'keypressfcn', @detectFirstKeyPress);
   waitfor(F);
 end

 % subfunctions (i.e. in same file) acting as callback functions
 function detectFirstKeyPress(CallerHandle, KeyPressEvent)
   if strcmp(KeyPressEvent.Key, '5')
     set (CallerHandle, 'keypressfcn', {@detectKeyPresses, tic()});
     fprintf ('Experiment started at %s\n', datestr(now()));
   end
 end

 function detectKeyPresses (CallerHandle, KeyPressEvent, StartTime)
   if strcmp (KeyPressEvent.Key, '5'); 
     global fMRIData; fMRIData(end+1) = toc(StartTime);;
     fprintf('"5" pressed at %d seconds.\n', fMRIData(end)); return
   elseif strcmp (KeyPressEvent.Key, 'escape');
     disp ('Escape Pressed. Ending Experiment'); 
     close (CallerHandle);
   end
 end
```

---

<sub>PS: Note that for a keypress event to be considered linked to the figure, the figure must be in focus. I.e. do not press '5' while the terminal is in focus, this won't be counted. Just launch the function and start pressing buttons as the window appears.</sub>

<sub>PS2: As an aside, if you *must* perform certain tasks asynchronously, matlab provides the [batch](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/batch.html) function for this. Also worth having a look.</sub>

Comment: You could have used ellipsis `...`

Comment: @SardarUsama I did initially, but then it looked weirder, hahah. That line is for cosmetic effect only anyway, no point dominating the code window. :p